# Reversed foreign key on an unmanaged model doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models

I've recentrly ran into a following problem.
I have a couple of unmanaged models

```
class A(models.Model):
    # some fields
    class Meta:
        app_label = "app"
        db_table = "table_a"
        managed = False

class B(models.Model):
    # some fields

    a_fk = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="b_objects")

    class Meta:
        app_label = "app"
        db_table = "table_b"
        managed = False
```

so, as you can see, I've added related_name="b_objects" which I need to access objects B from objects A via django ORM.

I need to get a count of B objects for each A object in my view, so what I do is:

```
class InventoryLocationsCollectionView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = A.objects.prefetch_related("b_objects").annotate(total=Count("b_objects"))
```

however what I get is an error that there's no such field 'b_objects' in A model.

I also tried to use

```
queryset = A.objects.raw("my query")
```

however it didn't work as it calls .all() somewhere under the hood and raw querysets do not have .all() method.

Also the difficulty is that I'm gonna need to add some filters and pagination raw queryset do not seem to support either.

Are there any workarounds to make reversed foreign key work in unmanaged models?

Update:

What worked for me is using annotate + RawSQL

```
queryset = A.objects.annotate(
    total=RawSQL("select count(1) from table_b where a_id = table_b.id", params=[]),
)
```

but the problem with this approach is that it's pretty slow. Besides total, I'm gonna need to query 3 more columns that will contain the number of b_objects, but with an additional condition, something like that:

```
london=RawSQL("select count(1) from table_b where a_id = a.id and city = 'London'", params=[]),
```

and I'll have 2 more cities which will slow down the performance significantly.

Maybe at least there's a way to optimize this RawSQL + annotate approach to reduce the number of subqueries from 4 to 1?

Comment: Normally it also lists the choicesof fields that are possible? Did you specify a `related_query_name` as well?

Comment: yes, I tried to add related_query_name in FK as well, but I still get the same error.
Yes, It lists the possible fields that I can use , and there's nothing like 'objects_b' mentioned there